# Is there a way to create a Workflow rule to reassign permissions?

Tags: workflow

After the Opportunity is set to Closed Won we would like only the Administrator and one other Key person to be able to update the record. Can I do this with a Workflow rule or would I have to create a trigger? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "reassign permissions?" You can simply use a validation rule to prevent saving changes on a record based on permissions, no need for a workflow or trigger. What do the Administrator and the other key user have in common? Do they both have the same profile?

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won'),
    NOT($Profile.Id = '*insert Profile ID of the admin users here*')
)
```

This will prevent anyone with that profile from being able to **save** changes to records once the Opportunity is Closed Won.

Alternatively, if they don't have the same profile, you can do it by User ID:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won'),
    NOT(
        OR(
            $User.Id = '*insert User ID here*',
            $User.Id = '*insert second User ID here*'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Brain, Thanks for your quick response I will get answers to your questions. I am new to this client and Salesforce.